# Why are my dots removed when i post a form?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, double

When I post my form, the points in my double are removed.
Does anyone have any idea what this is?

My model field:

```
[Display(Name = "Domeinnaam prijs:")]
public double DomainNamePrice { get; set; }
```

My HTML to fill the field in a form:

```
<div class="row">
        <label class="col-lg-3" style="margin:auto; font-size: 120%;" asp-for="DomainNameLine"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i.DomainNameLine, new {@id = "DomainNameCheckbox", @name = "DomainNameLine", @onclick = "DomainNameCheck()"})
            <span asp-validation-for="DomainNameLine" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DomainNameField" style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-lg-3" style="margin: auto; font-size: 120%;" asp-for="DomainNamePrice"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input asp-for="DomainNamePrice" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="DomainNamePrice"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For example, when I enter 14.99. I get 1499 as a result.

[The form field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8AnU.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQJw5.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi @Dylanhagmolen, I have tested your code but it works fine. Maybe you need share a minimum repo on github which can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Rena Thanks for the reply. The doubles did work. But suddenly not anymore. Could it be that I once started the project in vscode instead of visual studio? I have no idea how github works.

Comment: Hi @Dylanhagmolen, You mean your project works fine when run in vs but not working in vscode?

Comment: No, I just wanted to see if programming in vscode was more fun. So I opened the project is vscode, ran it, and the project did start. I hadn't looked at the doubles then. But now that I just continue working in visual studio, the doubles don't work anymore. I think it could have something to do with this.

Comment: @Rena When i remove this: <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />. Commas are working but dots dont. Actually the dots should stay so I can convert them to commas. Plus now I can't use data annotations anymore I guess. It's good that I can fill in commas. but when someone does the fuit and makes a point, there's nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

You appear to be using a server that is setup with a language that uses comma's instead of decimal places. You can adjust the culture to one that uses the comma's in a way that your application is designed, such as en-US.
or you can add this statement on the page:

```
<%@ Page uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont have <system.web>. I have <system.net>. Does that matter?

Comment: Hi @Dylanhagmolen, Can you look at this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=net-7.0